# Monogame Android - how to change surface format to Rgba8888 of game view

Tags: xamarin.android, monogame

I want to change surface format of game view in xamarin android to get transparent affect for monogame background in Android layout, but got exception when casting to AndroidGameView:

Here is my Activity code:

```
 public class Activity1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            this.SetContentView(TestFBX.Resource.Layout.layout1);
            var gameWindowLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(TestFBX.Resource.Id.gameWindow);

            var game1 = new Game1();
            var game1View = game1.Services.GetService<View>();

            //Exception thrown here:
            game1View.JavaCast<OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView>().SurfaceFormat = Android.Graphics.Format.Rgba8888;

            gameWindowLayout.AddView(game1View);
            game1.Run(GameRunBehavior.Asynchronous);                   
        }
    }
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to convert instance of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MonoGameAndroidGameView' to type 'OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView'.
```

I am using Monogame 3.5.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have to reference to `OpenTK-1.0 dll` instead of OpenTK.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\OpenTK-1.0.dll
```